# How to make tar only match patterns to extract on a certain directory?

Tags: tar

The extracted `tgz` contains a structure approximately like:

- **Source**

  - header.h
  - bozo.h
  - **dir2**

    - anotherheader.h

The following:

`tar xzf libm.tar.gz --strip-components=2 Libm-2026/Source/*.h/`

extracts `header.h`, `bozo.h` and `anotherheader.h`. What would make it only extract the ones at the specified directory specifically – that is, only `header.h` and `bozo.h`?